# How to map return values of entityManager.nativeQuery to entity class?

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, dao

for example I have an entity class `Profile`.
`Profile` has `name`, `age`, `location` and some other fields.

In my DAO, I make a query like

```
Query q = entityMgr.createNativeQuery("SELECT name, age FROM Profile", Profile.class);
List<Profile> list = new ArrayList<Profile>();
list = q.getResultList();
```

Is this possible? To return only 2 fields and fit that into `Profile` entity?

EDIT:
I already tried this and an `Invalid column` error is produced.

Comment: Try it and see what happens

Comment: Please see EDIT not above.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a run-time error because it is not one of the errors thrown by getResultList(). So I'm assuming the error is in your query. Could you post the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is indeed giving invalid column error as you mentioned, then one workaround is to create empty column and name it using your entity's field name in your SQL:

```
Query q = entityMgr.createNativeQuery("SELECT name, age, '' as location FROM Profile", Profile.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not use native query, but I cannot see why you are wanting to use a native query in the first place.

You could also use a [constructor expression](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor) to return an class with just the required fields populated.

You could achieve this in your case as below:

```
List<Profile> profiles = entityMgr.createQuery(
"SELECT NEW com.myproject.Profile(p.name, p.age) FROM Profile p",
Profile.class).getResultList();
```

You will obviously need a matching constructor in your Profile class.

You need not only construct entities in this manner, you can construct any class, as long as you have a matching constructor and the class is fully qualified.

Comment: I tried this before sir but I had a problem when for example I have a query which should return name(string) and location(string) and another query which returns name(string) and email(another string) for example.

If I do this, I can only have 1 Profile(string, string) constructor, any workaround sir?

Comment: As I mentioned before, you need not only create entities in this way, so you could make a different class for each combination and then construct that object in the query. e.g. NameAndAgeProfile(String name, String age) and NameAndEmailProfile(String name, String email)

Comment: Thanks Trevor, although this solution is a little bothering.
What I want is to retain my entities and no additional class.